# Swift colorWithAlphaComponent() not working

Tags: swift, uiview

Hi I am using a simple view to draw a path with semi transparent yellow color but is not working.

```
let tYellow = UIColor.yellowColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there The view has its property called

```
var opaque = true
```

You must set it to `FALSE` to see the transparency at the UIView